# Selenium C# - Compare table values with available values

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

**Specflow:**

```
Then i verify the available fruits
   | fruits |
   | Apple  |
   | Orange |
```

`Xpath://div[@class='fru_cl']/span`      - this will return the collection of elements

inside my step definition:

converted table values into String List.

How can i get the values during runtime and have to compare and say which is not available! (Preferable Assertion to fail it)

Comment: Your post if very unclear in my opinion, do you want to get list of fruits that appears on the website, and compare it with your expected list?

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far in your step definition?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your input from specflow as a table:

```
public void MyTestMethod(Table table)
{
   IEnumerable<string> fruits = table.CreateSet<string>();

   //Assert Something
}
```